# How to fix UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a nuke command, but when I execute the command ($nuke) I get this error:

```
(node:3888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

This is my main.js nuke command code

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'nuke'){
    client.commands.get('nuke').execute(message, args);
  }
```

This is my nuke.js code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'nuke',
    execute(message) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            message.channel.send('missing permissions')
        }

        message.channel.clone().then(channel => {
            channel.setPosition(message.channel.position)
            channel.send('nuked')
        })
        message.channel.delete()
        
    },
};
```

The error is from

```
if(command === 'nuke'){
    client.commands.get('nuke').execute(message, args);
  }
```

Comment: How are you importing / instantiating the client. The error suggests that the `client.commands` is `undefined` which would mean that there is no property `commands` on the `client` object

Comment: `client.commands` is undefined. Did you try to define it with `client.commands = new Discord.Collection()`, or `new Collection()`, or `new Map()`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be, that you're never **setting** your commands to `client.commands`. In order to do that, you first have to create a new `collection` in your `index.js / main.js` (Your startup file).

#### Here's an example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Your other code

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

The simplest way to continue would be using a **command handler** to set all your commands automaticly. If you don't have one, here's mine:

#### command_handler.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
const fileArray = [];

const readCommands = (dir) => {

    const __dirname = rootDir;

    // Read out all command files
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));

    // Loop through all the files in ./commands
    for (const file of files) {
        // Get the status of 'file' (is it a file or directory?)
        const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));

        // If the 'file' is a directory, call the 'readCommands' function
        // again with the path of the subdirectory
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            readCommands(path.join(dir, file));
        }
        else {
            const fileDir = dir.replace('\\', '/');
            fileArray.push(fileDir + '/' + file);
        }
    }
};


readCommands(/*name of directory your commands are stored in*/);

for(const file of fileArray) {
        const command = require(`../${file}`);

        if(command.name) {
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }
    }
```

**Note that this file is in an own directory called `handlers`. Also it could be possible that you have to adjust some paths to your project structure**

Looks nice now, but in order to use it you have to call it in your `index.js / main.js` before logging in your bot:

```js
require(`./handlers/command_handler`)(client);
```

And that's pretty much it. Let me know if you have further problems, in this case simply join my Discord server linked in my profile. There are people that can help you aswell.